# DISM: "The specified package is not valid Windows package"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, dism

I'm running a Windows Server 2016. When executing `Dism /online /Get-Features` on the power shell, I get this output:

```
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.2457


Error: 0x800f0805

The specified package is not valid Windows package.
```

I have tried running the `Cleanup-Image` and `Restore-Health` commands countless times, to no avail. The dism.log file shows this probably relevant output:

```
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3960 TID=4988 Getting Provider DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3960 TID=4988 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Processing the top level command token(get-features). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Failed opening package @Foundation. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_CreatePackageByName(hr:0x800f0805)
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Failed to get the underlying cbs package. - CDISMPackageManager::OpenPackageByName(hr:0x800f0805)
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 The specified package is not valid Windows package. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Failed to open the Foundation package. - CDISMPackageManager::OpenFoundationPackage(hr:0x800f0805)
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 The specified package is not valid Windows package. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Failed to open the Windows Foundation Package as a fall back. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_GetFeatures(hr:0x800f0805)
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Failed while processing command get-features. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0805)
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3960 TID=4988 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
```

The cbs.log file lists this output for the relevant time:

```
2019-05-03 23:18:02, Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:UpdateOrchestrator, UpdateID:{904A6850-B94E-40EF-BBF8-524E9ECE9F90}, revision: 201
2019-05-03 23:18:03, Info                  CBS    Read out cached applicability from TiLight for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.1480.1.15, ApplicableState: 0, CurrentState:0
2019-05-03 23:18:11, Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:UpdateOrchestrator, UpdateID:{77CA678E-CF23-4B1E-BACD-46C54BBBB167}, revision: 200
2019-05-03 23:18:11, Info                  CBS    Read out cached applicability from TiLight for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.1358.1.9, ApplicableState: 0, CurrentState:0
2019-05-03 23:18:19, Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:UpdateOrchestrator, UpdateID:{32064542-82DA-4012-B925-5CDE2A58201D}, revision: 202
2019-05-03 23:18:19, Info                  CBS    Read out cached applicability from TiLight for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.1198.1.6, ApplicableState: 0, CurrentState:0
2019-05-03 23:18:26, Info                  CBS    WU creates the package, AppID:UpdateOrchestrator, UpdateID:{A4154C87-C19C-48BC-A5AA-4A7073D773F4}, revision: 200
2019-05-03 23:18:26, Info                  CBS    Read out cached applicability from TiLight for package: Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.1066.1.8, ApplicableState: 0, CurrentState:0
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  CBS    Session: 30736885_3295285420 initialized by client DISM Package Manager Provider, external staging directory: (null), external registry directory: (null
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  CBS    Not able to find an installed package package from moniker: @Foundation [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  CBS    Failed to resolve package from moniker [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
2019-05-03 23:18:35, Info                  CBS    Failed to OpenPackage using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f0805]
```

I have no idea what to do. Is there a way to "reset" this DISM thing? Or manually do whatever it fails to do itself?

Comment: I have sometimes been able to successfully repair damage to the CBS store by manually copying the relevant files from a working machine running the same OS version.  In this case it isn't obvious to me how to figure out which files are damaged.  Do you have a working Windows 2016 server to compare against?  Failing that, you might need to do a [repair installation](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: .... have you run a chkdsk?

Comment: I have neither another server to refer to available, nor did chkdsk resolve anything. I gave up and set up the entire system again, luckily it's not hosting anything critical yet.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am facing the exact same problem for the same execution and seeing similar logs.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I mentioned I did a reinstall of the system because I couldn't find another way.